# A file that contains many JSON, what is the definition of such file?

Tags: json, dictionary, file-format, jsonlines

I have a file that contains many dictionaries, each line with its own unique dictionary and there are many lines in this file.

```
{"text": "bla bla", "year": 1933, "price": 43}
{"text": "bla blu", "year": 1934, "price": 41}
{"text": "blu bla", "year": 1935, "price": 43}
{"text": "blu blu", "year": 1936, "price": 44}
```

Just wanted to emphesize that the dictionaries are not inserted into a list, this is just the way it is, each new row in the file contains a dictionary.

Comment: If you prepend `[` and append `]`, then replace `\n` by `,` you get an array of dictionaries, wich is JSON-conform.

Comment: JSON requires double quotes, so the dictionaries in the example are not valid JSON.

Comment: @str I edited the question, it's double quotes as you said and not I wrote before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a JSON Lines text file format : http://jsonlines.org/

> JSON Lines text format, also called newline-delimited JSON. JSON Lines is a convenient format for storing structured data that may be processed one record at a time. It works well with unix-style text processing tools and shell pipelines. It's a great format for log files. It's also a flexible format for passing messages between cooperating processes.

Comment: I use this format very often. It's very usefull to share complex model between differents language